# How to get an autoincremented ID immediately after inserting a new record

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My script takes a CSV file containing people's details and inputs them into my mySQL database table using "INSERT INTO table". The primary key of the table is their ID number which is auto-incremented on each insertion.

I will have some PHP after each insertion to make a directory for them on the server. The directory name is their auto generated mySQL ID number.

How could I get their auto-generated ID number after inserting their details in to the database so I can make the directory for each person?

Comment: By inserting the data one row at a time and grabbing last insert id?

Comment: Are you inserting one row at a time?

Comment: How about `mysqli::$insert_id` -- mysqli_insert_id — Returns the auto generated id used in the last query? Would this do what you need?

Comment: Inserting one row at a time, yes

Comment: well what are you using? **mysqli_*** ?? **PDO** ??

Answer (score 1):

**PDO:**

```
$last_id = $db->fetchAll('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as last_id');  
$last_id = intval($last_id[0]['last_id']);
```

#### OR

```
$lastId = $db->lastInsertId();
```

Comment: dont answer this question... there is already an exact way to do it (a few minutes after I marked it as a duplicate)... a duplicated question only clutters the community.. its much better to just close the question and if anyone finds this question they will be redirected to the other post...

Comment: this is a very genious way using SQL to get last id.

Comment: @IlyasMimouni which was already used [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680943/pdo-get-the-last-id-inserted)

Comment: @JohnRuddell, well, i opened question and went out :D came back and answered. i didn't saw your mark...

Comment: @IlyasMimouni for pdo i remember just this, for mysqli are more ways...

Answer (score 1):

here is a complete example with rollback:

```
<?php 
try { 
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'username', 'password'); 

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO test (name, email) VALUES(?,?)"); 

    try { 
        $dbh->beginTransaction(); 
        $tmt->execute( array('user', 'user@example.com')); 
        $dbh->commit(); 
        print $dbh->lastInsertId(); 
    } catch(PDOExecption $e) { 
        $dbh->rollback(); 
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "</br>"; 
    } 
} catch( PDOExecption $e ) { 
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "</br>"; 
} 
?>
```

we use PDO to communicate with database, and to know to last id : $dbh->lastInsertId()

Answer (score -5):

You may use the  mysqli_insert_id function.

[docs here.](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

Comment: you should NEVER tell someone to use **mysql_*** as its deprecated.. also the OP is using PDO so this technology wouldn't even work

Comment: @JohnRuddell It's "it's"

Comment: @Strawberry I smell a grammar nazi :P

Comment: I know, I know - but I can't help myself.