# How to get last created ID

Tags: php, mysql, deprecated

No matter what I try - I cant seem to pull the last created id of the query I inserted to mySql.

I read here about syntaxes that are deprecated and all sort of code that wont work.

I tried both functions (I use bigint) so I understand that this is how to go:

```
if (($result = $conn->query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()")) === FALSE) {
  die(mysql_error()); 
}

if ($result->fetch_assoc()) {

$id = $row[0];
echo $id;
}
```

but nothing!!

**Can someone please just give me a full simple php code sample of how to do it?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680943/pdo-get-the-last-id-inserted might help

Comment: Don't use mysql_* it has been deprecated

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the last inserted ID of a MySQL table in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685860/how-do-i-get-the-last-inserted-id-of-a-mysql-table-in-php)

Comment: Nop, what I am asking for (and actually was just replied) it is nowhere to be found.

Comment: See, What you are asking is still unclear. Your code are totally wrong. Not getting from where to help. Format your question in meaningful way. OK

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$result = $conn->insert_id; to know last inserted row`

Comment: or any of the methods described in the manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Comment: Thank you!!!
and let me add that the $result you wrote might be confusing cause it is not an object. it returns a string.

SO: 
echo $conn->insert_id;
prints the last generated id.
(Im using MyIsam, BigInt, Autoincrement index)

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the last insert Id,

echo mysql_insert_id();

Answer (score 0):

Dont use **mysql** its depricated, instead use **mysqli** or **PDO**. To get last inserted record use **mysqli_inserted_id()**. The following shows the snipped how to use-

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "dbname") or die('Facing some problem connecting with database');

$query = "INSERT INTO `table_name` VALUES (v1, v2, v3...vn)";
mysqli_query($link, $query);

printf ("New Record with id %d inserted", mysqli_insert_id($link));
```