# Get id of last post displayed in table

Tags: php, mysql

In code below I will be displaying posts in table. Now for creating load more function I need to get id of last post in table but I am not able to do that, Here `$ID = $row['id'];` gets me id of first post may be because it's outside loop and to get id of last post I must place this code inside loop. But where to exactly place it so that I get id of last post displayed in table.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id desc limit 3";
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$ID = $row['id'];
?>

<table>
<tr>
<?php do { //horizontal looper?>
<td>
<div><h2><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h2></div>          
<div><p><?php echo $row['body']; ?></p></div>
<img src='<?php echo $row['pic']; ?>'>
<div><p><?php echo $row['about']; ?></p></div>
</td>
<?php
$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if (!isset($nested_List)) {
$nested_List= 1;
}
if (isset($row) && is_array($row) && $nested_List++%3==0) {
echo "</tr><tr>";
}
} while ($row); //end horizontal looper 
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Simply use `$id = $db->lastInsertId();` after `$query->execute();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDO get the last ID inserted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680943/pdo-get-the-last-id-inserted)

Comment: @Uchiha I am not talking about database table

Comment: please read question again its not duplicate of what you have marked, I am displaying posts in a table(not db table) so i want to catch id of post that is displayed at last in table

Comment: hello, you need only last entry of post in  database table  right?

Comment: @darshandave not db table ,,, I am displaying posts in table, i want to get id of that last post displayed in table

Comment: Your "//horizontal looper" with that `$nested_List++%3==0`-thingy seems overly complicated (esp. given the "LIMIT 3" clause). You just want to display up to three items hoizontally next to each other and if there are more items in the database have a "next"-link?

Comment: @VolkerK yes horizontal loop works well three posts are displayed horizontly(like columns) but I can't catch id of last post displayed

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :-

```
    $ID1 = $row[0]['id'];//first id of table
    $ID2 = $row[1]['id'];//2 id of table
    $ID3 = $row[2]['id'];//3 id of table
```

get latest id:-

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id desc limit 1";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Query

```
<?php 
 try { 
 $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'username', 'password'); 

 $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO test (name, email) VALUES(?,?)"); 

  try { 
    $dbh->beginTransaction(); 
    $tmt->execute( array('user', 'user@example.com')); 
    $dbh->commit(); 
    print $dbh->lastInsertId(); 
  } catch(PDOExecption $e) { 
    $dbh->rollback(); 
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "</br>"; 
} 
 } catch( PDOExecption $e ) { 
   print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "</br>"; 
 } 
?>
```