# Getting last id PDO

Tags: pdo, lastinsertid

This is what i have:

```
$stmt = $handler->prepare('SELECT id FROM users');
$stmt->execute();
$id = $handler->lastInsertId();

echo $id;
```

So, i want result to be for example "There is $id registered users".

Comment: `lastInertId` is available after a successful INSERT operation. You want to `SELECT MAX(id)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Row count with PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/883365/row-count-with-pdo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never need to select the "last id" from a table. Every time you think you you need it, you need something else. For example, whatever "Last id" has nothing to do with the number of users registered. Instead, you have to *count* users:

```
$count = $handler->query('SELECT count(id) FROM users')->fetchColumn();
echo "There is $count registered users";
```

Comment: `SELECT id FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1` This is also working but maybe it's not the right one, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> `PDO::lastInsertId` -- Returns the ID of the last *inserted* row or sequence value.
>   — https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php.

What you want is a *count* of registered users, see [Row count with PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/883382/934739).

To retrieve the last inserted ID or sequence value see [PDO get the last ID inserted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680943/pdo-get-the-last-id-inserted).

Comment: He don't need the count of *results*. Simply because he don't have them.

Comment: The word "results" can be used if you selected some data, got some results and then want to count them. While the OP don't have any query results. the only result he have is the count itself and obviously there is no point in counting it.