# Take ID after database insertion / MySQL / PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I want to take the ID of a row just after its creation. Im using PDO.

Here is my code:

```
$insertNewIndividualConv = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO conv_individual(user1, user2, created) VALUES(:user1, :user2, :created)');
$insertNewIndividualConv -> execute(array(

    "user1"=>$user1verif,
    "user2"=>$user2verif,
    "created"=>date("F j, Y, g:i a")

     ));

//Extract ID of this new row here
```

Thank you.

Comment: Read docs: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680943/pdo-get-the-last-id-inserted#10680965

Comment: Thank you @JustOnUnderMillions