# Show last id of database in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to get the last id number of Database. But It's showing only 0.
I am learning PDO. Can anyone tell me how can I do it?

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename";
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute();
  $row = $stmt ->fetch();
  $showid = $pdo->lastInsertId();
  echo $showid;
}
```

Comment: what is in your `lastInsertId()`?

Comment: You don't insert anything here, that's why insert id is not available.

Comment: @MammaMia: "It's showing only 0"

Comment: `lastInsertId()` to quote the manual, *Returns the ID of the last inserted row*; your query was a SELECT query, not INSERT. You probably want something like `SELECT table.id FROM table ORDER BY table.id DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: My last insertid should be 2

Comment: `lastInsertId` doesn't works like that. Check its documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php . If your ids are auto incremented, then the last id is the bigger.

Comment: @I mean what value id did you insert?

Comment: my Id is autoincrementing.

Answer (score 6):

`lastInsertId` will return the ID of a row that was inserted by the same connection. You can't use it outside of that context.

The easiest way to fetch the last ID would be to run something like,

```
SELECT max(id) FROM tablename
```

If you're using this in order to work out which ID should be inserted next, consider using an auto-increment column for your ID instead.

Answer (score 0):

`lastInsertId()` works only after a `INSERT` query - since you're only doing a select, it will always return string(1) = 0

So either you perform this code after an `INSERT` statement, or you can do the following:

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
$lastId = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

Refering here to: [PDO get the last ID inserted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680943/pdo-get-the-last-id-inserted)

Visit this thread, you'll find my samplecode provided by Corbin and much more informations on this topic.

Comment: I tried your link and then It shows only 0 but this is supposed to show 2. Any Clue ?