# Getting last insert id and inserting it into db php MVC

Tags: php

I am trying to get the last inserted id in the database and use that to insert another record(s), in this case, associated images with a particular record. Note: I am using MVC and this is in the model. These 2 operations should happen straight after each other i.e.: the user does't see that there are 2 different inserts happening at the same time.

This is the initial insert:

```
public function addAccom($data)
    {
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `accommodation` (`name`, `description`, `category`, `slug`) VALUES (:name, :description, :category, :slug)");
        $this->db->bind(":name", $data['name']);
        $this->db->bind(":description", $data['description']);
        $this->db->bind(":category", $data['category']);
        $this->db->bind(":slug", $data['slug']);
        if($this->db->execute()){
        $id = $this->db->lastInsertId();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I don't know if this line is correct in the above:

```
$id = $this->db->lastInsertId();
```

After this insert, I need to insert more records into another table using that id.

Should I try run another db query in the same query as this or create another query?

This is the second query I had:

```
public function addAccomPic($data)
{
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `accom_pics` (`accom_id`, `pic_name`) VALUES (:accom_id, :pic_name)");
    $this->db->bind(":accom_id", $data['accom_id']);
    $this->db->bind(":pic_name", $data['pic_name']);
    if($this->db->execute()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Database:

```
private $host = DB_HOST;
    private $user = DB_USER;
    private $pass = DB_PASS;
    private $dbname = DB_NAME;

    private $dbh; // Is this the same as $link ?
    private $stmt;
    private $error;

    public function __construct() {
        $dsn = "mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->dbname";
        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );

        try {
            $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);

        } catch(PDOexception $e) {
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
            echo $this->error;
        }
    }
```

Comment: $this->db->insert_id is what you looking for and pass that id to your other method

Comment: is this mysqli? what sql api you're using? var_dump your $this->db

Comment: I am using PDO.

Comment: ops thats for mysqli, sorry didn't bother to ask, then you're correct, and just pass it to your next method

Comment: Getting error: `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Database::lastInsertId()`

Comment: not familiar with PDO yet but query and bind? or should it be prepare and bind?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDO get the last ID inserted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680943/pdo-get-the-last-id-inserted)

Comment: I don't think I need to bind it because it is only created once the database record is inserted?

Comment: @Akintunde, not sure this is a duplicate because I am using MVC?

Comment: this is a dup. check the answer there. You are obviously using a custom class in the `$this->db`. show where `$this->db` comes from. the class i mean

Comment: @user8463989 no dude, you do it like this http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php what I mean is binding is you're binding your value into a param inside your statement/query

Comment: @Akintunde, `private $db;

 
 public function __construct()
 {
  $this->db = new Database;
 }`

Comment: Please, stop making "database classes". You already have one: PDO.

Comment: this code is not PDO, so removing the tag. and yes, I have no idea why people are so eager to create a database class if they have no idea how to use it afterwards

Comment: I have resolved the issue after spending lots of time on google. I am wrapping PDO in a database class it would seem which apparently isn't the best thing to do. That is what I learned through a tutorial so perhaps I learned a bad practice there? But anyway, I shouldn't be using stmt->, I should be using return $this->dbh->lastInsertId();

It now works.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing i see, it's $id is a local variable. Try to set it as global:

```
public $id = null;

public function addAccom($data)
{
    $this->id = $this->db->lastInsertId();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am getting this error: ` Undefined property: Database::$insert_id`

Comment: Error is in the first method? when you call $this->id ?  $data['accom_id'] become $this->id;

Comment: Yes, I commented out the second method and I still get the same error

Comment: $this->execute return true?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking?

Comment: please post PDO connection that you create

Comment: All my other database transactions work fine. There is just an issue with that one line. I have added what you asked for ( I think) to the original question