# PHP upload image , different queries

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO memberadd (username,password,profilepic) VALUES ('$username','$password','$profilepic')";
```

The code above is register with image upload

```
$imagedataprofile = "INSERT INTO imagedbgallery (postid,imageupload) VALUES ('$postid','$profilepic')";
```

the code above is trying to pass the data to another table

my memberadd table (below)

> userid(PK) |  username |  password |  profilepic

my imagedbgallery table (below)

> imageid(PK) | userid |    imageupload

**the things that i try to achieve is that when user insert a record:**
memberadd table will show

```
1 | tommy | 12345 |tommyprofile.png
```

**and in imagedbgallery table will show**

```
1,1,tommyprofile.png
```

===========================================================================
But when i tried to run the code,

memberadd table will show

```
1 | tommy | 12345 |tommyprofile.png
```

and in imagedbgallery table will show

```
1,0,tommyprofile.png
```

Comment: And what's the question? Do you get some error? Show what you have tried please

Comment: No error, however when i tried to run the code , in my imagedbgallery table , the userid is 0. the question that i want to ask is that where did i do wrong ? the answer that i want is when i i try register, the imagedbgallery table will show userid(from memberadd table)

Comment: Hem because you don't insert it

Comment: @JulesR , oh , then how should i insert it ?

Comment: Please update the question with the correct answer and the issue you get

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDO get the last ID inserted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680943/pdo-get-the-last-id-inserted)

Answer (score 0):

just set the userid(PK) autoincrement in your memberadd table then execute the query

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO memberadd (username,password,profilepic) VALUES ($username, $password, $profilepic)";
 mysql_query($sql);
```

now fetch the last inserted id using this query

```
$lastId = mysql_insert_id();
```

now pass this id in

```
$imagedataprofile = "INSERT INTO imagedbgallery (imageid, postid,imageupload) VALUES ($lastId, $postid, $profilepic)";
```

Comment: tried the code, but imagedbgallery  is not updating

Comment: did you execute the first sql query like this mysql_query($sql);  before this $lastId = mysql_insert_id(); ?

Comment: yeah , sorry my bad for the lack of explanation , as in not updating is that (same result, still showing 0 )

Comment: Please don't use mysql_query!!! This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0.

Comment: it may be because you still haven't set userid as autoincrement in memberadd table in xampp or wamp server whichever you are using

Comment: yeah you are right it is removed in php7, you can go for the mysqli_query. read the docs here http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php