# Insert multiple rows in one column

Tags: php, mysql

I want to assign multiple vehicles in one reservation if i click the add button. Here is my code;

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['cid']))
{
    $cid=intval($_GET['cid']);
    $tid=intval($_GET['tid']);

    $sql = "UPDATE tblbooking SET VehicleId=:cid WHERE  id=:tid";

    $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $query -> bindParam(':cid',$cid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query -> bindParam(':tid',$tid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query -> execute(); 

    $msg ="Vehicle Successfully Assigned. ";


}
```

I tried *INSERT INTO* but I am not going anywhere.Does anyone know how to revise this code? I want my output to be like this;

```
|booking_id|VehicleId|
----------------------
|1         |1        |
|1         |2        |
----------------------
```

Comment: Your `booking_id` in second row should be `1` as in first row. It's N-M relation, so your `booking` entity will have multiple `vehicles` and it's all joined via third table `tblbooking`

Comment: Also your binding fails, because you should use `:cid` and `:tid` in query instead of direct `$cid` and `$tid`. E.g. `UPDATE tblbooking SET VehicleId=:cid WHERE  id=:tid`

Comment: I already incorporated your suggestions and edited my post

Comment: So what's wrong then? You should execute 2 queries for both vehicles

Comment: See these examples https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/update

Comment: It's just updating the *VehicleId* column and not adding the new assigned :cid

Comment: Why would an UPDATE appear in a question about INSERTS?!???

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE statement with named placeholders
adding both values into 1 column

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['cid']))
{
    $cid=intval($_GET['cid']);
    $tid=intval($_GET['tid']);

    $bothValues = $tid.','.$cid; //adding both values in to 1 column

    $sql = "UPDATE tblbooking SET VehicleId = :VehicleId WHERE  id=:id";

    $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $query -> bindParam(':VehicleId',$bothValues, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query -> bindParam(':id',$tid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query -> execute(); 

    $msg ="Vehicle Successfully Assigned. ";
}
```

Comment: It is shows the success message but assigning blank value

Comment: Do if statement to see if you get values from html form `if(empty($cid) || empty($tid)){
 echo "Empty values";
}`

Comment: I added $lastInsertId = $dbh ->lastInsertId();

 if($lastInsertId)
  {
  $msg="Vehicle Successfully Added.";
  }
  else 
  {
  $error="Something went Wrong!";
  }
      
   } but it shows error message

Comment: Sorry but your question was for "Insert multiple rows in one column", Check this : PDO get the last ID inserted https://stackoverflow.com/a/10680965/12232340