# PHP SQL assign LAST_INSERT_ID() into a variable

Tags: php, mysql, session-variables, last-insert-id

I am trying to assign `LAST_INSERT_ID()` into a variable. When I use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` it works but when I do `$id = LAST_INSERT_ID();` it doesn't work.

Works:

```
INSERT INTO pooruser (userid, name) values (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'Jack')
```

Doesn't Work:

```
$id = LAST_INSERT_ID(); 
INSERT INTO freeuser (userid, name) values ('$id', 'Jack')
```

I'm not really sure why it won't work. If anyone can help me I would greatly appreciate it!

Also if I can get this to work to store that in a session would I then do `$_SESSION('id') = $id;` ?

Again, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You are using `LAST_INSERT_ID()` wrong:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("...");
$stmt->execute();
$id = $db->lastInsertId();
```

If you want to do it with SQL instead of the PDO API, you would do it like a normal select query:

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
$lastId = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

Resource: [PDO get the last ID inserted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680943/pdo-get-the-last-id-inserted)
Here examples for other connections: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_lastid.asp

For session:

```
$_SESSION['id'] = $id;
```